# What is Screen views on CSV export on Firebase Analytic Dashboard?

Tags: firebase-analytics

Please help me tell about what is "Screen views" and why it's double number? How to calculate it?

[image: Evidence image here]

Answer (score 0):

Screen views are used to track how long a user might be on a specific screen.

> Google Analytics tracks screen transitions and attaches information about the current screen to events, enabling you to track metrics such as user engagement or user behavior per screen.

You can read more about it in the documentation [**HERE**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/screenviews) and create your own manual screen tags

Comment: "screen views" on CSV export file is time on specific screen. Right?

Comment: Do you know how to calculate it?

Comment: I believe it is minutes per page, so dividing by 60 should yield hours.

Comment: I mean when it starts and ends to count? Google is not mention about it